# PyQt QWebView Email access

Tags: python, ide, pyqt, qwebview

Is there a way to access a website (e.g. email) through the QWebView widget in monkey studio using python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Email is not a website; can you be more specific what you want? In general, if you can create Qt widgets, you can create a web-view.

Comment: Sorry I meant a website in general. I was just wondering if you knew a way of displaying a webpage on the widget as I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#load) I think it's pretty clear:

```
wv = QtWebKit.QWebView()
wv.load( QtCore.QUrl( 'http://www.google.com' ))
wv.show()
```